# Problem in No script tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, noscript

Im placing no script tag on my master page that if a user dont have javascript enabled or its browsers doesnt support javascript it redirect to a specific view. im using this code

```
 <noscript>    
  <% Response.Redirect("../UserLogin/Error");  %>
 </noscript>
```

but the problem is its redirecting me everytime i open the page although my javascript is enabled. Im using asp.net mvc2 what may be the problem or is there is any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag `noscript` is evaluated in the client (browser). The server doesn't know if client has script support, so every time it redirects.

---

**EDIT**

Explain better: the server just creates a string (HTML) and send it to browser. It doesn't parse to see if browser has script support.

---

**EDIT 2**

You can use [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag. See:

```
<head>
    <noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/" />
    <!-- Redirect to http://example.com/ immediately -->
    </noscript>
</head>
```

I tested in firefox and works.

Comment: You can't do that - "However, you can’t use `noscript` inside the `head` to provide alternatives for JavaScript functions, as that would involve writing content inside the head element." - http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/noscript

Comment: @Jiang Sorry, but I tested now and works. At least in firefox. It isn't W3C compilant, but works. :)

Comment: Well, I'd change my words to "You *shouldn't* do that" then ;)

Answer (score 3):

`Response.Redirect` is executed on the server side and it will send a 302 status code to the browser which will automatically redirect. You probably want:

```
<noscript>    
    Please enable javascript to use this site.
</noscript>
```

Comment: +1 for brevity. I would add that a js-based redirect to the main site is also a possibility, though a bit of a hack...